# Validation Error not being displayed (MVC4 and EF)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

The invalid login error message is not being displayed for incorrect username or password. I have a Model called User and a Controller with the Action Method Validate, which validates the username and password. Upon successful validation I redirect to Create Action method, if not I add a model error and I want to display an "Invalid username or password" message on the login screen.

```
Model:

public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [MinLength(10)]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    [Display(Name="Mobile No")]
    public string PhoneNum { get; set; }
}

    Controller:

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Validate()
    {

        return View();

    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Validate(User user)
    {


        var u1 = db.Users.Where(p => p.UserName == user.UserName && p.Password == user.Password).FirstOrDefault();
        if (u1 != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
        else
        {

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Validate");


    }

    View:

    @model HindiMovie.Models.User

    @{ViewBag.Title = "Login";}

    <h2>Login</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false,"The user name or password provided is incorrect.")

    <fieldset>
    <legend>User</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>





    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Validate" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirecting resets the `ModelState`. You probably want to re-display the view instead:

```
public ActionResult Validate(User user)
{
    var u1 = db.Users.Where(p => p.UserName == user.UserName && p.Password == user.Password).FirstOrDefault();
    if (u1 != null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View();
}
```